# webpack - use unminified library version when dev

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I have a TypeScript project that uses forked apexcharts npm package. I would like to use unminified version of apex charts lib when building project with webpack *develpement* mode, for *production* i would like to stay with minified. Apexcharts package provides both minified and unminified versions of the library.

Is it possible to configure webpack this way? What configuration steps should be performed?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: I do not see any value in using a minified version of a library, when you package it with Webpack. Webpack/Terser Plugin will minify it for you.

I believe you can achieve your goal by using [Resolve aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)

Snippet (untested)

```
const alias = {};

if(isDev) { // NODE_ENV === 'development' or mode etc.
  alias['apexwhatever'] = path.resolve('path/to/unminified.js');
} else {
  alias['apexwhatever'] = path.resolve('path/to/minified.js');
}

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have already made it a bit different. In fact I'm using a fork o apex charts so i have extended build configuration to build apexcharts.esm.js in dev mode. Webpack seems to use this file from apecharts package to build my project. In the end for dev mode apex is not minified, and for prod it is - and that was the goal.